# How to do a wp_query with two acf-fields, sorting on one of them

Tags: wp-query, advanced-custom-fields

I have two Advanced Custom Fields, *footnote* and *date_edited* (a datepicker-field). What I want to achieve is to run a **wp_query** where *footnote* is not empty. The output I want sorted based on *date_edited*.

I have tried multiple solutions without being able to solve this.

This is my best try:

```
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'page',
    'meta_query' => array(
        'relation'      => 'AND',
        array(
            'key' => 'footnote',
            'value'   => array(''),
            'compare' => 'NOT LIKE'
        ),
        array(
            'key' => 'date_edited',
            'value'   => array(''),
            'type' => 'DATE',   
            'compare' => '='                                        
            'orderby' => 'meta_value_num',
            'order' => 'DESC'
        )
    ),
    'post_status' => 'publish',
    'posts_per_page' => 10,
    'no_found_rows' => true
);
```

Obviously this is not working. -And it's the *date_edited* array that is not correct. Does anyone see my errors, and have a correct solution to show?

**EDIT after @majick responded**

This works. And is a small modification of @majick's suggestion:

```
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'page',
    'meta_query' => array(
        array(
            'key' => 'footnote',
            'compare' => 'EXISTS',
        ),
    ),
    'post_status' => 'publish',
    'posts_per_page' => 10,
    'no_found_rows' => true,
    'orderby' => 'meta_value_num',
    'meta_key' => 'date_edited',
    'order' => 'DESC'
);
```

Comment: Clean up your code pleas so that it starts on the left, and not right of the middle of the page.

Comment: How can you even think about comparing a value to an array? the code do not make sense on very basic level

Comment: Done! Sorry for poor formatting.

Comment: @MarkKaplun You are right. Maybe I shouldn't work on this while being feverish...

Comment: always better to get well first ;) the orderby and order also seem to be out of place

Comment: @MarkKaplun, yes, it was the orderby and order that was the initial reason for my question. But unless someone outright codes the correct solution for me, I think I'll just leave this until my brain is working again... :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are just confusing the array levels, ordering is not done inside the meta_query level but on the main query level. It is the difference between two classes:

https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query
https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Meta_Query

Also, as the meta query codex says: "Custom field value can be an array only when compare is 'IN', 'NOT IN', 'BETWEEN', or 'NOT BETWEEN'"... I think you really only need NOT EQUALS here to check footnote value is set... I don't think you need to check if date_edited exists so you have a much simpler query:

```
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'page',
    'meta_query' => array(
        'key' => 'footnote',
        'value'   => '',
        'compare' => 'NOT EQUALS'
    ),
    'post_status' => 'publish',
    'posts_per_page' => 10,
    'no_found_rows' => true,
    'orderby' => 'meta_value_num',
    'meta_key' => 'date_edited',
    'order' => 'DESC'
);
```

Hope this helps... and that your fever has broken? :-)

Comment: Thank you! Unfortunately, the fever is even stronger. Your suggestion _almost_ works! Please see my updated question for the changes I made, and what works / don't work. The challenge now is the ordering. It orders by _footnote_ no matter what I try. I will respond as soon as I find the correct answer! (Which might take a while...)

Comment: ah sorry typoed it, that should me `meta_key` not `metakey`

Comment: also recommend raw garlic and ginger :-)

Comment: Thank you for the heads up! :) -And you know what? That solved it! (Correcting the typo I mean.)

Comment: (Unfortunately I don't have enough "reputation" to upvote your answer...)

Comment: no probs, and "correct" answer is better than upvotes anyway. :-)